# optimal k for knn algorithm in item based recommendation system using cross-validation

Tags: algorithm, cross-validation, knn, nearest-neighbor, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to make a recommendation system in my Graduation project app using k-nearest neighbor algorithm.

I make an item recommendation system to recommend products to the active user based on products rating.
my dataset is a matrix filled from the database, the columns represent the system's users, and the rows represent the products in the system, and the matrix filled with the rating values for each product from each user. as the following example 
 [image: dataset example] , 
but in my case there is products not movies.

there is now 17 products(rows) and 12 users (columns). but I want an accurate general way to find k .

I used k=sqrt(n)/2 as an equation to find a good k value (n represents the number of products in the application). but I want more accurate way to find the k value, someone give me an advice to use k-fold cross-validation, after searching, I understood how to use cross-validation for classification. 
Can anyone explain to me how to use it in Recommendation systems?

Comment: Probably a better fit on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this copy if you post there.

Comment: Hello, I agree with @DavidEisenstat that stats.SE might be a better site for this question. Regardless, there are some things unclear about your question. KNN is generally an algorithm for classification (or regression) and it is unclear how you want to apply it to recommendation. K-fold cross validation is an evaluation method, and has no direct link to KNN. "k" is simply a variable that mathematicians tend to use for small natural numbers, but it does not have a single meaning. The "k"s in KNN and K-fold CV are unrelated. Lastly, can you perhaps just try each k and check which is best?

Comment: I agree with everything @ADdV said other than the fact that KNN can be used for recommender systems. It's usually not the most powerful model, but it works.